# How to read image from Hosted Server and display in Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, image, razor

I'm Developing a website in MVC Razor view. There I have  provided option of downloading the Excel file. And its is working fine. I just need to attach an image at the top of excel file. I have published in localhost the image is showing, whereas from other system image not showing only content is showing, below is my code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td height="50">
            <img src="@Context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/company_logo1.png")" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">
            <h3>Mini Statement</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <table cellspacing="1">
                @foreach (JProperty s1 in Model.DownloadData.SelectToken("MiniAccDet"))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">@s1.Name</td>
                        <td style="mso-number-format:@myVariable;" font-weight:bold;" align="left">@s1.Value.ToString()</td>
                    </tr>
                }
                @foreach (JProperty s2 in Model.DownloadData.SelectToken("MiniStmtBal"))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">@s2.Name</td>
                        <td style="font-weight:bold;" align="left">@s2.Value</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so you want excel cells to display image ?

Comment: Exactly the i wanted

Comment: Any idea how to get the image shown in excel file?

Comment: I have never applied it...but if I were to... I would have used the bas64 way